# How to get api data using jquery ajax?

Tags: php, jquery, json, api

In this code I have a normal dropdown where I have some city name. Now, What I actually want when I change any city then through jquery I want to get `json` data in my alert box which is not working yet. I don't know why? So, How can I do this?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#city").change(function() {
    name = $(this).val();
    console.log(name);
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      dataType: "json",
      data: {
        "name": name
      },
      url: "http://postalpincode.in/api/postoffice/" + name,
      success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="city" id="city">
  <option value="">Select City</option>
  <option value="delhi">delhi</option>
  <option value="ghaziabad">ghaziabad</option>
  <option value="noida">noida</option>
  <option value="meerut">meerut</option>
</select>
```

Comment: The site you're trying to request seems broken. `ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID`

Comment: Show us what happens on the PHP side. Try `var_dump($_POST);` to make sure PHP is receiving the data.

Comment: 1. I am unable to see any jQuery library added.2 check your browser console tab to see that any error occur or not?3. instead of `alert(data);` do `console.log(data);` and check any data coming or not? (again check browser console tab)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/qy4kfj0m/16/  `Mixed Content: The page at 'https://fiddle.jshell.net/_display/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://postalpincode.in/api/postoffice/noida'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.`

Comment: I made you a snippet, it should work - the site accepts GET too but does not support HTTPS - I added jQuery for you in case that was the issue, but it would not work from an HTTPS site

Comment: if your site is `https`, then trying to load a `http` url (`http://postalpincode.in/api/postoffice/`) will fail

Comment: @mplungjan  what if the main problem for OP is that he didn't added jQuery library?

Comment: @AlivetoDie - that is possible - but now he knows

Comment: @AlivetoDie Additionally my chrome actually switches the http to https and gets an invalid cert :O

Comment: Perhaps you should change API: https://data.gov.in/resources/locality-based-pincode-15th-february-2016/api#/Resource/get_resource_7eca2fa3_d6f5_444e_b3d6_faa441e35294 https://www.quora.com/What-does-the-parameter-mentioned-in-API-of-data-gov-in-mean

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please check below code

```
<select name="city" id="city">
    <option value="">Select City</option>
    <option value="delhi">delhi</option>
    <option value="ghaziabad">ghaziabad</option>
    <option value="noida">noida</option>
    <option value="meerut">meerut</option>
</select>
```

Ajax Called

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#city").change(function(){
            name = $(this).val();
            /*For PHP called is for Cross-Origin Request Blocked*/
            $.ajax({
               type:"GET",
               dataType: "json",
               data:{name: name},
               url:"test.php",
               success:function(data)
               {
                   alert('Get Success');
                   console.log(data);
               }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

PHP file code for Cross-Origin Request Blocked -

```
<?php 
$name_city = rawurlencode($_GET['name']);
$url = "http://postalpincode.in/api/postoffice/".$name_city;
$curl_handle=curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_URL,"$url");
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
$postoffice_data = curl_exec($curl_handle);
curl_close($curl_handle); 
$postoffice_data = json_decode($postoffice_data);
echo json_encode($postoffice_data);
exit;
?>
```

Comment: But I want to know that how to get data after success. I am using `var myObj = $.parseJSON(data);
       myObj.PINCode;
                   alert(data);
                   console.log(data);` which is not working.

Comment: @Rudra Update this code in PHP file 

`$postoffice_data = json_decode(json_encode($postoffice_data));
echo json_encode($postoffice_data);`

Comment: I got solution @PraveenKumar. Thank you so much for reply